# How to generate row-major and column-major matrices in java?

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying to work through an assignment that is asking me to create a method in Java that, when given a desired height and width, create a row- or column- major matrix.

[image]
Here is what I have so far:

```
public static int[][] increasingMatrix(int width, int height, boolean format){


        if (format) { // generate row-major matrix
            int[][] array = new int[height][];

            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                array[i] = new int[width];
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = count;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return array;

        } else {
            int[][] array = new int[width][];


            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                array[i] = new int [height];
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                    array[j][i] = count;
                    count ++;
                }
            }

            return array;
        }

    }
```

However, when I go and try to run tests on the generated array, the column-major matrix (from what I can tell) is being generated incorrectly. The row-major matrix seems to generate correctly.

Can you see anything that I am doing wrong? I have stared at this for hours but cant seem to get any breakthroughs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. The first index in the matrix is always the width.

Remember: a matrix is an array of arrays. The first index is the width of the matrix, the second is the height.

Try this:

```
if(format) {
    return buildRowMajorMatrix(width, height);
} else {
    return buildColumnMajorMatrix(width, height);
}
```

Where `buildRowMajorMatrix` looks like:

```
private int[][] buildRowMajorMatrix(int width, int height) {

    int[][] matrix = new int[width][height];
    int cellValue = 0;

    for(int columnIndex = 0 ; columnIndex < width ; columnIndex++) {
        for(int rowIndex = 0 ; rowIndex < height ; rowIndex++, cellValue++) {
            matrix[columnIndex][rowIndex] = cellValue;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

And `buildColumnMajorMatrix` looks like:

```
private int[][] buildColumnMajorMatrix(int width, int height) {

    int[][] matrix = new int[width][height];
    int cellValue = 0;

    for(int rowIndex = 0 ; rowIndex < height ; rowIndex++) {
        for(int columnIndex = 0 ; columnIndex < width ; columnIndex++, cellValue++) {
            matrix[columnIndex][rowIndex] = cellValue;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In else condition:

```
else {
        int[][] array = new int[width][];
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            array[i] = new int [height];
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                array[j][i] = count;
                count ++;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
```

You are trying trying to iterate through arrays (rows of matrix, j-index) that are not yet initialized. To implement column-major matrix you need to first initialize all rows (or switch to more complex algorithm).

Also I think width and height of matrix in both formats should be same. Row- and column-majority only says whether we fill matrix iterating by columns or rows, but I guess wording of the task leaves room for interpretation.

My solution:

```
public static int[][] increasingMatrix(int width, int height, boolean format){
    int[][] array = new int[height][width]; // Java's shortcut generating regular array of arrays for you
    int count = 0;
    if (format) { // generate row-major matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                array[i][j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)) {
             for (int i = 0; i < height; i++ {
                array[i][j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```